# Tag synonyms: convert, conversion, etc. tag consolidation

Tags: discussion

- [conversion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/conversion) should be synonymous with [format-conversion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/format-conversion)
- [convert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/convert) should be deleted or made a synonym of [conversion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/conversion)
- Should [video-conversion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/video-conversion) be a separate tag, or should this be rolled into 'conversion/format-conversion' as well?
- A related tag, [file-format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/file-format), seems like it might be able to stand on its own.

Seth's comment pointing out the weakness of 'file-format' seems valid. It would have to be more clearly defined. Could be related to questions on particular file formats -- e.g., tarj, gzip, 7zip, iso, cue, xml, csv -- that are not conversion questions, but use or content or programamtic interaction questions. Which isn't to say there's not a better overarching tag for those, or that the tag is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

[video-conversion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/video-conversion) should be removed. Its questions belong under [format-conversion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/format-conversion).

I personally don't see how [file-format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/file-format) can stand on it's own..